# Running npm run dev causes Nextjs to change my jsx property in ts config file

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tsconfig, npm-start

Whenever I run the following script to start up my Nextjs project:

```
"dev":"react-env --path APP_ENV=local -- next dev"
```

It somehow changes the following line in my `tsconfig.json` file from `"jsx": "react"` to `"jsx": "preserve"`.

Not sure why that is happening, nor how to fix it. The reason I want to fix this is because when I run Cypress I get the following error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./context/index.tsx 27:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:12)
```

Comment: Why do you want that? Emitting JSX as React.createElement will make it unable for babel/swc to transform it.

Comment: @brc-dd, I added the answer to your question in the OP.